# first time installing sanity and having a error which shows as following

Tags: tailwind-css, project, init, sanity, npm-start

Trying to install **sanity **for the first time I am facing error when **init, start etc**. Can anyone suggest me the answer. I tried to search it everywhere but unable to find it.

```
Error: Error while obtaining machine id: Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:286:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:484:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
    at C:\Users\pc1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@sanity\cli\node_modules\node-machine-id\dist\index.js:1:7964
    at exithandler (node:child_process:430:5)
    at ChildProcess.errorhandler (node:child_process:442:5)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:292:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:484:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

This step runs succesfully.

```
npm install --global sanity@latest
```

But this one don't.

```
npm create sanity@latest -- --template clean --create-project "Sanity Project" --dataset production
```